# How to implement Leave-One-Out with scikit learn

Tags: scikit-learn, cross-validation

I would like to implement Leave-one-out CV with scikit learn, but do not understand the guidelines on scikit learn internet site. I have 10 articles classified into two classes, five articles in each class. Do not know how to proceed after importing the articles with `load_files` option.
Some brainstorming would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I'm afraid that trying text analysis (let alone cross-validation) with just 10 articles would be useless. You'd need more data.

Comment: Hey, I want to compare my classifier with MN NB and for this I need leave-one-out CV. Can you help me out with some ideas? I tf-idf vectorized my articles but not sure how to use them in scikit learn LOO.

Comment: I think the example here http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_validation.LeaveOneOut.html is pretty clear. What exactly would you like some help on?